# .filter() versus .first() in django

Tags: django-models

```
>>> user = User.objects.filter(username='xyz')
>>> user
<QuerySet [<User: xyz>]>
>>> user.id
```

Gives error -> Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'id' in Django

But after applying .first() I get the correct user id

```
>>> user = User.objects.filter(username='xyz').first()
>>> user
<User: xyz>
>>> user.id
1
>>>
```

Why is it so ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
user = User.objects.filter(username='xyz')
```

Using only filter it will provide you all the users whose `username='xyz'`.
It can be many.

BUT

If you use `user = User.objects.filter(username='xyz').first()`

It will provide only the first object not all. It will return only one object of user whose `username='xyz'`.